# Java - Elasticsearch : sort based on distance

Tags: elasticsearch

This is my ES mapping

```
{
  "titan": {
    "mappings": {
      "tagLabelIndices": {
        "_ttl": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "tagLabel": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "objIndices": {
        "_ttl": {
          "enabled": true
        },
        "properties": {
          "objAddress": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "objGeoLocation": {
            "type": "geo_point"
          },
          "objTitle": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Now I want to do distance based search

```
public static String getTitleBasedQuery( String titleString)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(AppConstants.Common.property.objTitle);
    sb.append(":");
    sb.append(titleString);

    return sb.toString();
}

public static ArrayList<Long> esQueryExecuter(Client client,String query, int start, String sortOnField,int resultPerPage,String types,SortOrder order)
{
    SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
    .setTypes(types)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString(query))
    .setFrom((start-1)*resultPerPage).setSize(resultPerPage)
    .addSort(sortOnField, order)
    .execute()
    .actionGet();

    SearchHit[] results = response.getHits().getHits();
    ArrayList<Long> al = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for (SearchHit hit : results) 
        al.add(LongEncoding.decode(hit.getId()));
    return al;
}     


System.out.println(esQueryExecuter(esClient, getTitleBasedQuery("Matrix's rain javascript"), 1, AppConstants.Common.property.objGeoLocation.toString(), 10, "objIndices", SortOrder.ASC));
```

i got this error:

```
nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[can't sort on geo_point field without using specific sorting feature, like geo_distance]; }
```

again somewhere i saw `setFilter(GeoDistanceRangeFilterBuilder)` but this method was not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by distance requires a specific distance sort structure called [`_geo_distance`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_geo_distance_sorting) which you can build this way

```
SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
    .setTypes(types)
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString(query))
    .setFrom((start-1)*resultPerPage).setSize(resultPerPage)
    .addSort(SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort(sortOnField)
        .order(order)
        .point(ORIGIN_LAT, ORIGIN_LON)
        .unit("km"))
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Note that you also need to input `ORIGIN_LAT` + `ORIGIN_LON` as a reference point from which to compute the distance to sort on.

If you need to add a range within which to search, you can do it with a [`geo_distance` filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html):

```
GeoDistanceFilterBuilder geoDistanceFilterBuilder = FilterBuilders.geoDistanceFilter(sortOnField)
  .point(ORIGIN_LAT, ORIGIN_LON)
  .distance(10, "km")
  .optimizeBbox("memory")
  .geoDistance(GeoDistance.ARC);

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("titan")
    .setTypes(types)        
    .setQuery(QueryBuilders.filteredQuery(QueryBuilders.queryString(query),
         geoDistanceFilterBuilder))
    .setFrom((start-1)*resultPerPage).setSize(resultPerPage)
    .addSort(SortBuilders.geoDistanceSort(sortOnField)
        .order(order)
        .point(ORIGIN_LAT, ORIGIN_LON)
        .unit("km"))
    .execute()
    .actionGet();
```

Comment: how can i add range within which i have search?

Comment: i think this is wrong there is no method called `setFilter`

Comment: You're right. Let's simply use a [filtered query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-filtered-query.html) instead

Comment: does it apply filter before query is executed?

Comment: Yes, this is the case with filtered queries.